# Error trying to test laravel/passport auth cicle

Tags: testing, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I'm issuing some problems with Laravel/Passport while trying to test the auth flow of my application...
The stranger thing is that it only happens when I'm on testing env. The expects the 200 http code but instead receive a 500.

I'm using the Laravel 5.8 version, I'm also have installed Horizon and Telescope. My PHP version is 7.3.4.

## My test

```php
public function testLogin()
    {
        $user = factory(\App\Models\User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->json('post', 'v1/login', [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

## My AuthController

```php
public function login(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
            throw_if(!auth()->attempt($credentials), UnauthorizedAccess::class, __('auth.auth_required'));

            $accessToken = $this->handleAccessToken($credentials);
            return response()->json($accessToken);
        } catch (UnauthorizedAccess $ex) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $ex->getMessage()
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

private function handleAccessToken(array $credentials)
    {
        $user = User::where(['email' => $credentials['email']])->first();
        $http = new Client();

        $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type'    => 'password',
                'client_id'     => $user->client->id,
                'client_secret' => $user->client->secret,
                'username'      => $credentials['email'],
                'password'      => $credentials['password'],
                'scope'         => '*',
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    }
```

---

This is the erro that is produced:

### on terminal

```
1) Tests\Feature\AuthTest::testLogin
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

### laravel.log

```
[2019-04-26 09:02:53] local.ERROR: Client authentication failed {"exception":"[object] (League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException(code: 4): Client authentication failed at /home/***/workspace/***/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:138)
[stacktrace]

[2019-04-26 09:02:53] testing.ERROR: Client error: `POST http://***/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
 {"userId":"52b19d0d-e0c5-4924-84ae-d07700c672df","exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException(code: 401): Client error: `POST http://***/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"Client authentication failed\",\"message\":\"Client authentication failed\"}
 at /home/***/workspace/***/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113)
[stacktrace]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error seems to be something with Guzzle itself while in testing env. That happens because Guzzle is set for the default env.

Then, I solve it following the answer gave by @lawrencedawson, that you can see [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/codecept-guzzle-and-mocking-responses?page=1)